# How to use QUERY in Google Sheets to return the row with the maximum date?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use `QUERY` to copy the most recent data in a category to another sheet.  See example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SfctADfOR02YYTLzKXcN_dTa3Bdmpnu_D1tNC2-oiGc/edit#gid=0).  The first sheet has the data I want to copy with the category (row 1 and 3) and the date the data was gathered (row 5).

On the second tab, I am trying to copy over only data that has the tag `6.Portions.B` in row 1, `Summative` in row 3, and *the most recent date* in row 5.

I have successfully used the QUERY command and double transpose to have only `6.Portions.B` and `Summative` data be copied to the second sheet. However, I am unable to get the `QUERY` command to show only the most recent date. I am trying to use the following:

```
=transpose(query(transpose(Data!$1:$15), "select Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15 where Col1 starts with """&C$2&""" and Col3 = 'Summative' and Col5 = max(Col5)"))
```

It is the `and Col5 = max(col5)` that isn't working (everything else is fine). Is there some way to further filter by only the most recent date? I have tried using the `Filter` command, but my range size varies unpredictably based on other factors not shown here, and I haven't been able to get that to work without knowing the exact size of the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort by the date column in descending order and limit the number of returned rows to 1:

```
 select ... where ... order by Col5 desc limit 1
```

Strictly speaking, "the row with the maximum date?" is not a well-defined concept: multiple rows may have the same date. If this happens, `query` will pick one of such rows.